# F# - Absolute pathname incorrectly formatted

Tags: string, f#, pathname

I have run into an issue that totally stumped me . I wanted to create a small class to convert a bitmap to an array of pixels. The bitmap is created through an absolute pathname, and the pathname I input (on a Windows10 OS) is

```
let path = "D:\Dev\images\test"
```

but, I suspect this happens at compile time , the string is formatted like this

```
"D:\\Dev\\images\test"
```

and of course it kills the program immediately. I am 99.9% sure that this is something going on with the IDE that I am forgetting. Adding @ at the beginning of the pathname or a double \ doesn't seem to do anything. I am totally stumped on what to do.

Edit: I have expressed myself rather poorly. By "Adding @ at the beginning of the pathname or a double \ doesn't seem to do anything" i mean that I tried both adding @ at the beginning outside of the string :
`@"D:\Dev\images\test"` and `"D:\\Dev\\images\\test"`both produce the same result displayed above, except for the fact that `D:\\Dev\\images\\test` produces an exact copy of itself, but it's still invalid by Win10 standards.
Finally , the error raised is a generic "invalid parameter". No code whatsoever modifies the path value. It is , in fact , the first instruction in main.

```
let main _ =
let path = Defaults.img_folder + "\\test"   //img_folder = "D:\\Dev\\images"
let f = new Bitmap(path)    //throws "invalid parameter" error here

let spr_img : pixel[,] =  (Array2D.init 
                            f.Width 
                            f.Height 
                            (fun x y -> new pixel(Defaults.full_cover , ConsoleColor_from_Color(f.GetPixel(x , y)) , Defaults.backgroundcolor)) ) 

let eng = new engine(w , h)
eng.create_and_register_sprite(new image(spr_img), 20 , 20 , 0)
eng.loop_on_key(
    {
        speed = 0.
        positionX = 20. 
        positionY = 20.
        positionZ = 20.
        quitting  = false 
    }, 
    updater   //external function
)
0
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided an actual error message.

Comment: You are not supposed to add @ at the beginning of the path, but rather before the string itself, like this: `let path = @"D:\Dev\images\test"`, otherwise \t in the string will become a tab.

Comment: Also, if that second string is something you have in your source, then there needs to be a double backslash in all three places. That's needed when you don't use @ before the string.

Comment: I have edited the original answer to be a little clearer and added the error message thrown. Apologies

Comment: Sorry, it is still not clear. Are you saying that the 'invalid parameter' is thrown at the let assignment line? What is the rest of your code?

Comment: I have added the entire main. The invalid parameter is thrown at the instancing of the Bitmap

Comment: To combine paths, use [`Path.Combine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0).  Don't combine them via string concatenation.  I.e. `let path = Path.Combine(Defaults.img_folder, "test")`.  By the way, are you really sure there is an image **file** at `D:\Dev\images\test`?  That looks more like a nested subdirectory than a file since it lacks an extension.